# Why Angular Universal Server Side Rendering get an error after deployment in Firebase Hosting?

Tags: json, node.js, angular, typescript, firebase

I am currently working on Angular using its 3rd party library such as Angular CLI/Angular Universal following this link https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-universal-rendering / and firebase hosting / and real-time database. And it working great on my local machine listening in, localhost:4000. I see it render server-side rendering smoothly and I see the HTML which I need for SEO friendly I use also lazy loading which improves the loading of web application performance very fast. Now, my problem is, after I deploy my Angular application with Universal Server-side Rendering also with lazy loading. I get this error saying, Error: could not handle the request and also if I just deploy without lazy loading I get this 3 errors,

```
1. Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < inline.318b50c57b4eba3d437b.bundle.js:1 

2. Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < polyfills.bf95165a1d5098766b92.bundle.js:1

3. Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < main.4871dfc6be55ccbf4c0b.bundle.js:1
```

HERE'S THE FOLDER STRUCTURE:

- dist => this is the build folder of the angular application

  - browser
  - server
  - server.js
- e2e
- functions => this is the build folder and I use to upload into firebase hosting

  - browser
  - node_modules
  - server
  - .eslintrc.json
  - index.js
  - package-lock.json
  - package.json
  - server.js
- node_modules
- server => I use to transpile index.ts to index.js

  - index.ts
  - tsconfig.functions.json
- src => main directory for the angular application

  - app

    - demo

      - buttons

        - buttons.component.css
        - buttons.component.html
        - buttons.component.spec.ts
        - buttons.component.ts
      - demo-routing.module.ts
      - demo.module.ts
    - app.component.css
    - app.component.html
    - app.component.spec.ts
    - app.component.ts
    - app.module.ts
    - app.server.module.ts
  - assets
  - environments
  - favicon.ico
  - index.html
  - main.server.ts
  - main.ts
  - polyfills.ts
  - styles.css
  - test.ts
  - tsconfig.app.json
  - tsconfig.server.json
  - typings.d.ts
- .angular-cli.json
- .editorconfig
- .firebaserc
- .gitignore
- firebase.json
- karma.conf.js
- package-lock.json
- package.json
- protractor.conf.js
- README.md
- server.ts
- tsconfig.json
- tslint.json
- webpack.server.config.js

FOR, src/app/app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { ButtonsComponent } from './demo/buttons/buttons.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'buttons', loadChildren: './demo/demo.module#DemoModule' },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: 'buttons' }
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule.withServerTransition({ appId: 'something-unique-id' }),
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [
    AppComponent,
    ButtonsComponent
  ]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

FOR, src/app/app.server.module.ts

```
 import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
    import {ServerModule} from '@angular/platform-server';
    import {ModuleMapLoaderModule} from '@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader';

    import {AppModule} from './app.module';
    import {AppComponent} from './app.component';

    @NgModule({
      imports: [
        // The AppServerModule should import your AppModule followed
        // by the ServerModule from @angular/platform-server.
        AppModule,
        ServerModule, 
        ModuleMapLoaderModule // <-- *Important* to have lazy-loaded routes work
      ],
      // Since the bootstrapped component is not inherited from your
      // imported AppModule, it needs to be repeated here.
      bootstrap: [AppComponent],
    })
    export class AppServerModule {}
```

FOR, src/main.server.ts

```
export { AppServerModule } from './app/app.server.module';
```

FOR, src/tsconfig.server.json

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    // Set the module format to "commonjs":
    "module": "commonjs",
    "types": []
  },
  "exclude": [
    "test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ],
  // Add "angularCompilerOptions" with the AppServerModule you wrote
  // set as the "entryModule".
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "entryModule": "app/app.server.module#AppServerModule"
  }
}
```

FOR, .angular-cli.json

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "project": {
    "name": "kuntento"
  },
  "apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist/browser",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico"
      ],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
      "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "styles": [
        "styles.css"
      ],
      "scripts": [],
      "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
      "environments": {
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    },
    {
      "platform": "server",
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist/server",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico"
      ],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.server.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.server.json",
      "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "styles": [
        "styles.css"
      ],
      "scripts": [],
      "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
      "environments": {
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    }
  ],
  "e2e": {
    "protractor": {
      "config": "./protractor.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "lint": [
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
      "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
    },
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
      "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
    },
    {
      "project": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
      "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
    }
  ],
  "test": {
    "karma": {
      "config": "./karma.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "defaults": {
    "styleExt": "css",
    "component": {}
  }
}
```

FOR, ./server.ts

```
    import 'zone.js/dist/zone-node';
    import 'reflect-metadata';

    import { renderModuleFactory } from '@angular/platform-server';
    import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';

    import * as express from 'express';
    import { join } from 'path';
    import { readFileSync } from 'fs';

    enableProdMode();

    const app = express();

    const PORT = process.env.PORT || 4000;
    const DIST_FOLDER = join(process.cwd(), 'dist');

    const template = readFileSync(join(DIST_FOLDER, 'browser', 'index.html')).toString();

    const { AppServerModuleNgFactory, LAZY_MODULE_MAP } = require('./dist/server/main.bundle');

    const { provideModuleMap } = require('@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader');

    app.engine('html', (_, options, callback) => {
        renderModuleFactory(AppServerModuleNgFactory, {
            document: template,
            url: options.req.url,
            extraProviders: [
                provideModuleMap(LAZY_MODULE_MAP)
            ]
        }).then(html => {
            callback(null, html);
        });
    });

    app.set('view engine', 'html');
    app.set('views', join(DIST_FOLDER, 'browser'));

    app.get('*.*', express.static(join(DIST_FOLDER, 'browser')));

    app.get('*', (req, res) => {
        res.render(join(DIST_FOLDER, 'browser', 'index.html'), { req });
    });

    app.listen(PORT, () => {
        console.log(`Node server listening on http://localhost:${PORT}`);
    });

FOR, ./webpack.server.config.js

const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    entry: { server: './server.ts' },
    resolve: { extensions: ['.js', '.ts'] },
    target: 'node',
    externals: [/(node_modules|main\..*\.js)/],
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: '[name].js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            { test: /\.ts$/, loader: 'ts-loader' }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
            /(.+)?angular(\\|\/)core(.+)?/,
            path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
            {}
        ),
        new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
            /(.+)?express(\\|\/)(.+)?/,
            path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
            {}
        )
    ]
}
```

FOR, package.json

```
{
  "name": "universalrendering",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build --prod",
    "build:ssr": "npm run build:client-and-server-bundles && npm run webpack:server",
    "serve:ssr": "node dist/server.js",
    "build:client-and-server-bundles": "ng build --prod && ng build --prod --app 1 --output-hashing=false",
    "webpack:server": "webpack --config webpack.server.config.js --progress --colors",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^5.2.6",
    "@angular/router": "^5.2.0",
    "@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader": "^5.0.0-beta.5",
    "angular-universal-express-firebase": "0.0.4",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "express": "^4.16.2",
    "firebase-functions": "^0.8.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.6",
    "ts-loader": "^3.5.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.19"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.7.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.2.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.3",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "^4.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~4.1.0",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "^2.7.2"
  }
}
```

THIS IS FOR Firebase Hosting:

- server forlder

FOR, index.html

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as angularUniversal from 'angular-universal-express-firebase';

export let server_rendering = angularUniversal.trigger({
    index: __dirname + '/browser/index.html',
    main: __dirname + '/server/main.bundle',
    enableProdMode: true,
    browserCacheExpiry: 1200,
    cdnCacheExpiry: 600
});
```

FOR, tsconfig.functions.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es2015",
        "rootDir": ".",
        "outDir": "../functions"
    },
    "files": [
        "index.ts"
    ]
}
```

- functions folder
- functions => this is the build folder and I use to upload into firebase hosting

  - browser
  - node_modules
  - server
  - .eslintrc.json
  - index.js
  - package-lock.json
  - package.json
  - server.js

FOR, package.json

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "./node_modules/.bin/eslint .",
    "serve": "firebase serve --only functions",
    "shell": "firebase experimental:functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "~5.8.1",
    "firebase-functions": "^0.8.1",
    "@angular/animations": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^5.2.6",
    "@angular/router": "^5.2.0",
    "@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader": "^5.0.0-beta.5",
    "angular-universal-express-firebase": "0.0.4",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "express": "^4.16.2",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.6",
    "ts-loader": "^3.5.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.19"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^4.12.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^3.6.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

FOR, index.js

```
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
const angularUniversal = require("angular-universal-express-firebase");
exports.server_rendering = angularUniversal.trigger({
    index: __dirname + '/browser/index.html',
    main: __dirname + '/server/main.bundle',
    enableProdMode: true,
    browserCacheExpiry: 1200,
    cdnCacheExpiry: 600
});
```

Comment: "universal": "ng build --prod && ng build --prod --app 1 --output-hashing=false && webpack --config webpack.server.config.js --progress --colors && node dist/server.js"

Comment: Add above in your package.josn and then run npm run universal and then deploy

Comment: Otherwise try with https://github.com/hamedbaatour/angularfire-lite

Comment: @SantoshShinde thank you for this script I will try it. By the way, is AngularFire-Lite supported lazy loading and deployment in firebase hosting?

Comment: yes, please check demo to here https://github.com/hamedbaatour/angularfire-lite-demo

Comment: thank you so much for your help. I get an error saying, Cannot read property 'length' of undefined. By the way, what are the requirements using the AngularFire-Lite? Then how to deploy it in firebase hosting?

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/5053

Comment: If the source folder is not found/readable or no source files are found, then the length of files is undefined.

Comment: the project is running now with server-side rendering now I'm wondering how to deploy it in the firebase in right procedure.

Comment: Have you checked https://medium.com/@hamedbaatour/angular-5-server-side-rendering-with-firebase-step-by-step-guide-ec5f4d8ef38b ?

Comment: ok I check it. But do I need to configure something in Firebase? Like the database or something settings?

Comment: you need to install the dependencies

Comment: wow it works! but I'm having another some problem in my console, it has 3 errors, 1. Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < inline.318b50c57b4eba3d437b.bundle.js:1 

2. Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < polyfills.bf95165a1d5098766b92.bundle.js:1

3. Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < main.4871dfc6be55ccbf4c0b.bundle.js:1

Comment: means token not defined ?

Comment: yes, I get this error token not defined :)

Comment: have you create production build and then deploy on firebase ?

Comment: run on terminal first ng build -prod

Comment: have you create production build and then deploy on firebase? answer: YES i run ng build -prod

Comment: by the way, I see some hashing in the browser folder but in the server there's nothing is that important?

Comment: I still getting this either i run npm build --prod

Comment: which version of webpack are you using ( 1 or 2) ?

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/8820

Comment: currently installed is "version": "3.11.0"

Comment: By the way how to check? I agree with the assessment by @MaximeMorin here. Please check your web server's redirect settings.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165804/discussion-between-santosh-shinde-and-fred).

Answer (score 0):

Please check the same issue [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/8820), usually that error when your redirect rules are sending the index page instead of the javascript.

Update your `package.json` `scripts` as like follows:

```
        "scripts": {
          "ng": "ng",
          "start": "ng serve",
          "build": "ng build --prod",
          "build.server": "ng build -aot -app ssr",
          "test": "ng test",
          "lint": "ng lint",
          "e2e": "ng e2e"
        },
```

And then `.angular-cli.json` `"main": "main.ts"` to  `"main": "main.server.ts"`.

**Build browser and server versions of the app**

```
npm run build
npm run build.server
```

Please check the tutorial to here [Deploy Angular Universal w/ Firebase](https://hackernoon.com/deploy-angular-universal-w-firebase-ad70ea2413a1) and [demo](https://github.com/aaronte/angular-universal-firebase).

Hopes this will help you !!

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! Somehow I get console problem 3 errors saying, 1. Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < inline.318b50c57b4eba3d437b.bundle.js:1 2. Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < polyfills.bf95165a1d5098766b92.bundle.js:1 3. Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < main.4871dfc6be55ccbf4c0b.bundle.js

Comment: I still getting this either i run npm build --prod

Answer (score 0):

My problem was in the supervisor.conf file. The line with the environment in node was misspelling. The correct line is:

environment=NODE_ENV=production

This causes all my 'unexpected token <' problems

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue to you and was able to resolve it by moving my server.js file from the DIST folder into the directory above.

So my folder/file structure looks like this:

- webroot - root folder

  - server.js
  - dist (folder)

    - browser (subfolder)
    - server (subfolder)